# Problems with pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

So I recently installed the pygame extension for python, but I am having some trouble getting it to work. I am using python version 2.7.8, and on of the pygame versions I have tried are from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame), got the 2.7 32 bit version. 
I also tried the pygame.org site and downloaded pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py2.7.msi. 
I used a code I found online to test pygame out from [here](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=move_with_walls_example.py)
but when I try to run the program, all that comes up is a black window with the pygame icon on the top. If I try and click anywhere or do anything the program crashes with a "program not responding" window. 
Can somebody tell me what is wrong or things I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried running the code and got an error message saying:

```
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

So My conclusion Is that the guy in the video is using Python3.x because if I'm not misstaking super() doesn't require any arguments in 3.x

I don't know if you got this error message but You could at least try my solution:

In Python 2.7.8 super() needs arguments, so you need to modify the code like this:

```
super(Player, self).__init__()  #Line 48 in the example you linked to
super(Wall, self).__init__()    # Line 97 in the example
```

for me that fixed it. 
Another thing woth thinking about when working with GUI libraries like pygame is that the python GUI can interfere with the pygame code because pygame also tries to create a GUI. To avoid this you can run the program from, for example cmd instead.